# How to output onclick event only if field was filled by the user

Tags: javascript, php

I have a contact form and I want to block/disable the onclick event if the `name` field is not filled.

I tried this on the submit button:

```
<button class="btn btn-danger" <?php if (isset($view_post['nome']))?>onclick="window.open('http://somelocation.com','mywin','width=500,height=500');"<? endif() ?> type="submit">Enviar mensagem</button>
```

But it did not work.

Could someone help me?
Thank you

Comment: Change the endif like Jack said. And also make sure you don't have a typo in your condition `isset($view_post['nome'])` or `isset($view_post['name'])` ?

Comment: This is your 18th question. By that time, you should already have some idea what should a good question look like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `$view_post['nome']` is probably set but empty. Try this instead:

```
if(!empty($view_post['nome'])) {}
```

Also I'm not so sure about your weird `endif()` stuff. I would do it like this way:

```
<button class="btn btn-danger" <?php 
 if (!empty($view_post['nome'])) { ?>
     onclick="window.open('http://somelocation.com','mywin','width=500,height=500');"
 <? }
 ?> type="submit">Enviar mensagem</button>
```

That way I'm sure what is contained within the `if`.

Comment: thanks! it i think is working now,  but if i want put more fields like $view_post['phone'] , $view_post['address'] . How is it?

Comment: That's a different question. I think you should write some code in the beginning that decides and creates a variable, like `$can_click`, set to `true` or `false`. In the HTML, you'll then just check `if($can_click)`. Otherwise, your code will be very ugly.

Comment: is wrong write `<?php  if (!empty($view_post['nome'] && $view_post['phone'] && $view_post['address'])) { ?>` ?

Comment: Not wrong. But It's always better to separate complex code from HTML. It's up to you to decide how you write the code as long as you obey the rules of syntax.

Comment: but i got blank page `<?php  if (!empty($view_post['nome'] && $view_post['telefone'] && $view_post['empresa'] && $view_post['email'] && $view_post['mensagem'])) { ?> ` :( something is wrong

Comment: This is not a chat. Accept answer to this question and create a new one or find an IRC channel where someone will help you in real-time.

Comment: wtf o.o ok, thanks anyway

Comment: Do not *wtf* me and read rules of sites you're using.